# Сохранение переданных аргументов при навигации между фрагментами в Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-fragment, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

Есть 3 фрагмента: A - главный экран, с которого можно перейти к фрагментам B или C. Если перешли на фрагмент B, мы можем вернуться к фрагменту A с аргументами или без них. Для фрагмента C аналогично. Может, кто-нибудь, пожалуйста, подсказать как в compose нужно сохранять аргументы и состояние фрагмента (что-то похожее на работу Fragment result API)? То есть я могу передать аргумент с фрагмента B на фрагмент A. Но мне нужно потом перейти на фрагмент C и из него уже снова вернуться к A, т.е. я не должен потерять переданные аргументы из B, и в результате на фрагменте A должны быть аргументы как с фрагмента B, так и с C.

```
    // Переход к фрагменту B из фрагмента A

     navController.navigate(Screens.B.route) {
         launchSingleTop = true
     }

   // Из фрагмента B в A

   navController.currentBackStackEntry
                            ?.savedStateHandle
                            ?.set(
                                key = ArgumentKey,
                                Argument(
                                    parameter1,
                                    parameter2
                                )
                            )
                        navController.navigate(Screens.A.route) {
                            launchSingleTop = true
                        }
```

Comment: Т.е., сейчас, если у меня уже есть аргумент с экрана B или с экрана C и я перехожу на экран B (если в C аргумент получен) или перехожу на фрагмент С (если в B аргумент получен) то аргументы уже зануляются. Есть ли хороший способ их сохранить, кроме того как добавить "navController.currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set(.................." для каждого перехода для каждой кнопки

Comment: Не знаю про Fragment result API, но есть же вьюмодели - в них можно хранить состояние,  а не в savedStateHandle

Comment: В принципе да, можно sharedviewmodel сделать, просто еще хотелось разного посмотреть про compose, режимы запуска и другие способы сохранения состояние) Ну ладно, ограничусь общей вьюмоделью)

Comment: вьюмодель для этого и существует. Ну есть еще rememberSaveable(), но оно для другого.